# How do I print this for loop in another class and how do I return its value?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, printing

Okay, so I have this class that creates an array of student profiles with five using a multi argument constructor while the last using a zero argument constructor. Then I set each value of the array to one of the student profiles and I used a for loop to traverse the array.

My question is how do I use the array to return that value back to the method so I can call it from a different class to print? What tactic should I do because I'm not exactly sure how to do this with toString() and I'm kind of a new to all of this. Probably not best to do System.out.println for this but this is all I know what to do.

Furthermore, when i compile it says that they are incompatible types. That is why this isn't going through and I don't know how to put this back into a string instead of an int(?)

```
public class Applicants
{
   private Application[] applicant;
   public String Applicants()
   {
    Application student1 = new Application("Blair", "C", "Bass");
    Application student2 = new Application("Daniel", "R", "Humphrey");
    Application student3 = new Application("Charlie", "L", "Trout");
    Application student4 = new Application("Damascus", "L", "Roberto");
    Application student5 = new Application("Sofia", "M", "Montrone");
    Application student6 = new Application();

    applicant[0] = student1;
    applicant[1] = student2;
    applicant[2] = student3;
    applicant[3] = student4;
    applicant[4] = student5;
    applicant[5] = student6;

    for (int index = 0; index < applicant.length; index++)
    {   
         return System.out.println(applicant[index]);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could change your method signature to return an array, and initialize the array. Java method names start with a lower case letter (by convention). Something like,

```
public Application[] getApplicants() {
    return new Application[] {
            new Application("Blair", "C", "Bass"),
            new Application("Daniel", "R", "Humphrey"),
            new Application("Charlie", "L", "Trout"),
            new Application("Damascus", "L", "Roberto"),
            new Application("Sofia", "M", "Montrone"),
            new Application()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'print' method to your Application class.  This class will print the specifics of the particular instance of the Application.  Then add a method called 'print' to your Applications class.  This method should have a loop similar to the one you have above, but the innards should be something like `applications[i].print();`.

Now you can say something like this from a main routine:

```
Applications apps = new Applications();
apps.print();
```

The point here is to let the Application class handle the specifics of an Application. The Applications class should be handing details of managing groups of Application.

edit - finally, don't let the array of Applications leave the Applications class. If you do, you'll be unable to control the use of them.

Answer (score 0):

Method **public String Applicants()** expect to return an object type String, however, **System.out.println(..)** method does not return any object (void). That's why you got an **compile error**.

I suggest the following changes to your code:

1- Change method public String Applicants() to a constructor to populate the Application[] applicant array. Or change the method name to **public void populateApplication()** to avoid confusion and have meaningful name.

2- In method **populateApplication()**, you just need to populate the array with new values.

3- Create new methods to return all applicants or applicant by index:

```
public Application[] getAllApplications()
{
   return applicant;
}
```

and return by index, or other criteria ( eg: name):

```
public Application getApplicationByIndex(int index)
{
   if (index < applicant.length) //make sure the index is in the array boundary.
   {
       return applicant[index];
   }
   return null;
}
```

The caller will be the one who decide what to do with the return result, ie. print, modify, etc.

Hope that's help.